# sbt multiple native packages

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

So using Scala Play Framework. I have a single codebase but need to launch it 2 ways. One way will launch with Play Netty as the main class, and run a webserver. A second way will run my own main class and do different things.

If I do play dist  (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist)

It ends up using the sbt-native plugin, and make a new zip. Inside that zip is a script that calls java with a mainclass of Netty. This is ultimately coming from

```
  mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("play.core.server.NettyServer"),
```

inside of PlaySettings.scala.

I want to keep all of this, but add a second artifact to dist.. that has the only different of a different main class.

I started trying to make subprojects.. but not sure this is what I really even want.  Something like:

```
lazy val root = Project(
  id = "root",
  base = file("."),
  librar
  aggregate = Seq(web, backend)

).dependsOn(web, worker)

lazy val web = Project(
  id = "web",
  base = file("."),
  settings = packageArchetype.java_server ++ Seq(
    name := "web",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("play.core.server.NettyServer")
  )
).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val backend= Project(
  id = "backend",
  base = file("."),
  settings = packageArchetype.java_server ++ Seq(
    name := "backend",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("com.foobar.BackendMain")
  )
)
```

But I only end up with a single artifact still.  What other options are there?

I could hack up bash-template and add mainClass as a parameter and pass it through to the launch script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one main class as a default one and pass 
`-main you.another.class.Name`
parameter to bash script to run another main class.

Comment: I think this works with real sbt-native-packager.  But as far as I can tell, the play start script is stripping out the -main param.  Down inside my play generated start script I have ```declare -r app_mainclass="play.core.server.NettyServer"
```.    So one option is to try and figure out where this is being generated in play, and take the mainclass as a param like sbt-native normally does..

Comment: In run() function you should have  

`if [ -n "$custom_mainclass" ]; then`  
    `mainclass="$custom_mainclass"`    
  `else`  
    `mainclass="$app_mainclass"`   
 `fi`  
and declared `app_mainclass` will be ignored during start up with `-main` option

Comment: that is not in my run function made by play 2.3.9 via ```play dist``` .. but I am not seeing how they took that out, thus not seeing how I would hack it back to the normal play-native-package style.. what you posted is quite ideal.

Comment: Take a look to [bash-template](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/bash-template) lines from 237 to 255.

Comment: This is what the play generated file looks like:   ```  # check java version
  if [[ ! $no_version_check ]]; then
    java_version_check
  fi

  # Now we check to see if there are any java opts on the environemnt. These get listed first, with the script able to override them.
  if [[ "$JAVA_OPTS" != "" ]]; then
    java_opts="${JAVA_OPTS}"
  fi
```

Comment: Did you try pass -main parameter? Could you post your bash script?

Comment: Not sure what main will do if the script isn't using it. Here is the script play 2.3.9 generates for my app:  https://gist.github.com/brianwawok/22714eef3860ddce2477

Comment: Do you use any native packager specific build options? What version do you use?

Comment: This is what ships with Play 2.3.9, I do not set anything outside of play. Download a play sample app and do "play dist" and you can see or yourself.

Comment: think I fixed this by updating the SBT native plugin to 1.0, so then we had a mainclass option to pass in